# I use reactive form in my ionic app it give error

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dictionary, ionic4

page.html

```
            <form [formGroup]="directionForm">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating">Source</ion-label>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="source" formControlName="source"></ion-input>
         </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
         <ion-label position="floating">Destination</ion-label>
             <ion-input [(ngModel)]="destination"  formControlName="destination"></ion-input>
           </ion-item>
          <ion-button expand="full" type="submit"  
          (click)="calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionForm.value)" 
           [disabled]="directionForm.invalid">Get Direction</ion-button>
            </form>
```

page.ts

```
        import {FormBuilder,Validators,FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

      constructor(

        private fb: FormBuilder,

        ) {
        this.createDirectionForm(); }



        createDirectionForm() {
          this.directionForm = this.fb.group({
         'source': ['', Validators.required],
             'destination': ['', Validators.required]
            });
           }
```

app.module.ts

```
       import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

       imports: [ 

      FormsModule,

        ReactiveFormsModule,]
```

[image]

I used this form many times in my app. but now it gives an error. I don't know where am going wrong please help me to rectify this code thank you for your help

Comment: Import ReactiveFormsModule in MapPageModule

Comment: kindly provide error thrown